# Communicating between child to parent component in Angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular8

I am trying to communicate to my parent controller that a new item have been added in its child component. I am aware that for this I have to use @Output and event emitters, and I am using them, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: `"... but it doesn't seem to be working"` ← Please elaborate. What does "not working mean". Is the event firing but no data? Is the data not updated? What *exactly* is happening (or not happening)?

Comment: Is it a timing error? In `createNamespace`, you call a service, then subscribe to the result. In the subscription to that you are modifying `this.namespaces`, then emitting `this.namespaces` below it. But since the `this.namespaces` modification occurs in an observable, it is happening asynchronously and occurs after the value is emitted. Perhaps consider putting the emission within the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can create a "service" and have a multi-cast observable / subject (e.g. BehavioralSubject<>) push new values.

Here's a good starting point (btw, check out the other methods, too):

[Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Subject to do that. Here is the [link](https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/07/29/understand-subject-behaviorsubject-and-replaysubject/) to my blog for your ref

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {}

    sendMessage(message: any) {
        this.subject.next(message);
    }

    getData() {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

I defined 2 method here. The first method using next() to send message to the next subcriber. So in your component you just need to simply subscribe like this to get the data

```
private subscription$: Subscription;

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.subscription$ = this.messageervice
            .getData()
            .subscribe(data => { console.log(data); })
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription$.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `@Output` and event emitters (plus modified my project) and it worked. 
Turns out I didn't need to add a type to the event emitter:

```
@Output() public namespaceCreated = new EventEmitter<Namespace[]>();
```

Comment: *turns out i didn't need to add a type to the event emitter*...whilst true, I don't recommend leaving off the type and this should not be the cause of any issues. Typescript (via your IDE eg.g VSCode) will complain if you try to emitting a mismatched typed variable (which is helpful)